# Does supplemental Crucian information exist, and if so, where is it?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, races, world-building

As part of a new campaign, the table has decided to challenge itself by having a world populated with somewhat more non-traditional races. To that end, I am trying to find and use races which have some level of information regarding their society, tendencies, holidays, and other general cultural milieu.

Crucians, as a race, intrigue me in that they seem relatively versatile; like humans, while having a distinct fantasy "flavor" to be enjoyed.

However, I can only find the crucian in two sources, and both of them are quite scant on details. Outside of *Sandstorm* and *Miniatures Handbook*, was there ever any supplemental information on crucians? Perhaps an issue of *Dragon* or some other sourcebook gave them a more thorough treatment; something akin to what *Races of the Wild* did for raptorans, for example.

While this question is tagged dnd-3.5e, if there exists more cultural and social information in other editions, that would certainly go a long way in helping me craft a convincing crucian society.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, it does not appear that the crucians garnered any more focus than that provided them in their limited appearances in *Miniatures Handbook* and *Sandstorm.* My fairly exhaustive search of 1E and 2E monster resources suggests that crucians originated in the Miniatures Handbook, and while I had hoped to find some trace of them in the predecessor *Chainmail Miniatures Game* that existed immediately prior, I had no luck.

Searches of those 4E and 5E materials I have available, which is admittedly limited to the respective Monster Manuals of each edition along with the *Volo's Guide* monster resource from 5E, have been similarly unenlightening. All this is to say that as far as I can tell, crucians are one of the many one-off ideas from that era of D&D pseudo-setting work and never got fleshed out further.

That's not to say you can't flesh out some of the material that can be inferred from their brief descriptions - crucians seem to pursue both personal and group prestige, can be driven to great action by a persuasive warlord leader, may associate with sphinxes and possibly see them as wise or sagacious beings, and appear to eschew veneration of a deity in favor of druidic practice. Being a warrior race that fights internecine conflicts, elements of their culture relating to strength and death would pertain to those experiences as crucians see them - the power to break things, for instance, being associated with status and the might of the crucian race. They may have cultural touchstones involving their ancestors shattering some vast barrier or breaking the shell of a cosmic egg - the fragments of which formed the mountains, and the hole in the egg being the sky.

They are possibly fond of legal and contractual rigor, as a chiefly lawful neutral race who are noted as cunning negotiators who carefully weigh the words of others. Crucians speak Draconic and likely have regular contact with other races that employ that tongue - possibly including the brass and blue dragons that favor desert environments.

Anyway, I hope this has been of some help - I only wish I had more formal material to offer. Best of luck with your campaign!

Comment: Choosing to accept this answer as the conclusions it draws about crucians played out correctly - although HeyICanChan's fantastic answer was also "right" - this answer proved to hold more helpful content.

Comment: I'm pleased it could be of some value.

Answer (score 5):

The *Miniatures Handbook* appears to be the first appearance of the [crucian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crucian_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)). Besides there and *Sandstorm*, the only other text that I found mentioning crucians is the *Player's Guide to Eberron*, and even then just barely. *Player's Guide* On Races of Xen'drik says

> Countless other races, from the humanoid to the truly monstrous, inhabit the wilder regions of Xen'drik.… Ophidians, sarkriths, and crucians are all found in Xen'drik, as are many of the monstrous races also found in Khorvaire: ogres, minotaurs, harpies, gargoyles, and so on. (Ophidians and sarkriths are described in *Fiend Folio*; crucians appear in *Miniatures Handbook*.) (154)

This isn't much help, really: [Xen'drik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xen%27drik) is a "vast continent." They could be anywhere doing anything.

Anyway, so ignored are crucians that even the *Player's Guide* seems unaware of the crucians' republication a mere ten months earlier in *Sandstorm*. Well, I guess, not *totally* ignored—from the Design and Development Web column ["D&D: The Next Generation"](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/dd/20060630a) we learn from James Wyatt that the kids love those crucians:

> A session of *D&D* at our house usually means that I spend a half-hour pulling out minis that will make good encounters for our (usually three) characters, coming up with the most threadbare of plots (three crucians have been kidnapped—my son likes the crucian mini—and you need to rescue them), slapping down a map sheet from a *Fantastic Locations* product or a *D&D Miniatures* starter set, and sitting down to play through maybe three encounters….

Who knew, right? Just to be clear, in addition to published texts and Web adventures, the [*Dragondex*](http://www.aeolia.net/dragondex/monsters.html) lists no crucian entry, the remainder of the Wizards of the Coast Web site has nothing on crucians except for a couple of more mentions of them as part of the miniatures line, and the Consolidated List Web column [Monster Index](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/lists/monsters) lists them only twice.

I'm pretty sure that besides *Handbook*, *Player's Guide*, and whatever homebrew you can dig up on the Web—after eliminating all the [carp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crucian_carp)—, you're on your own.